# Where to archive code

Tags: coding-style, source-code

Say for example I have some unused code that I want to use in the future and does not work with the rest program,or say that I come across some interesting code online. Is there any good program that I can store different pieces of code in?

Comment: Emacs org-mode might be a interesting choice for taking notes and storing programs. It's powerful and especially suited to programmers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If it's for a program which is already under source control, just keep these changes in a branch of that repo.

For odd bits of code, you could use almost anything, but some good options would be private GitHub or Bitbucket repo, a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/), or some private source-control system you maintain on your own hardware. Non-source control options might include dumping things into an [S3 bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) or similar cloud storage system, esp. with your usage likely to not exceed the free pricing tier.

Comment: And there is always [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26674200)

Answer (score 2):

To my mind - these are 2 different questions:

**Unused code that I want to use in the future and does not work with the rest of the program**

If your [VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) system supports it, I'd be inclined to put this in a shelveset since it isn't current development but you may want to pull the code and work on it later.

**Some interesting code online**

Rather than pollute the source code tree with this, either bookmark the page or stash the code somewhere else (print it off, put it on the LAN, store it on a USB stick etc).

You may also want to email it to colleagues or add it to a wiki to raise awareness.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way to park your code is git. For example if you have a github account just create a repository there and put all your samples there.

I have something similar in my account and I call it [garbage](https://github.com/kavehmz/garbage)

It might be better than S3 or gists as you can organize/version/search your parked code easier.

Comment: [Gists](https://help.github.com/articles/about-gists/) are versioned (they're git repositories). They're also searchable if public.

Answer (score 0):

If it is part of your project, I would make a branch or a tag and then delete that code from your main repo.

I used to keep blocks of code in my main repo that served no other purpose other than that they might be needed later. Really what I was saying was that it might be useful later and I needed to find it. A tag might be even better as branches are supposed to be more ephemeral. [Branch vs Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457103/how-is-a-tag-different-from-a-branch-which-should-i-use-here)

In any case unused code will just confuse you and other devs later.  So it's not a great practice to leave it in a project.